# Opening an htm or html file with powerpoint on hyperlink click

Tags: html, microsoft-powerpoint

I have a powerpoint presentation on my website saved as htm file, an I am tring to open it not in my browser but in powerpoint on click.

Is there a possible way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

From [How to Convert HTML and Flash Files to PowerPoint](http://tiplet.com/tip/how-to-convert-html-and-flash-files-to-powerpoint/) :

> To import an HTML file, with
>   PowerPoint open click on `Insert`,
>   `Slides from Files`, and browse for
>   your file. PowerPoint will
>   automatically divide the file into one
>   or more slides. Select the slides you
>   want to import, and click “Insert” or
>   just click “Insert All” if you don’t
>   want to leave any out. Click “Close.”
>   Your new slide is on the screen and
>   you can manipulate it just as you
>   would any other slide.

Answer (score 0):

I think this Link will solve your problem:
http://pptfaq.com/FAQ00189.htm

Also try looking at this [Microsoft KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb;en-us;162059)